# Infinite loop on WP homepage

Tags: wordpress, infinite-loop

i'm having an infinite loop on the website homepage i'm working on.

I can access admin and all my website pages, but when i just type the homepage URL there's a constant refreshing loop...

- I checked that the website url is ok in the "Settings > General" menu : http://www.sandyheribert.com (i tried with and without "www", and also tried to enter the URLs using wp-confing file)
- I checked that the homepage exists of course and that it's the right one selected in the "Settings > Reading" menu
- I checked the .htaccess file, which is the default one (and i already tried to re-create it,
- I checked that there's no web redirection in my hosting provider,
- I disabled all plugins to check for an error but same result,

You can access the website by entering a direct URL like http://www.sandyheribert.com/contact/ and then navigate normally.

So, what am i missing ?
Thanks for any suggestion !

Comment: Have you changed the code for your home page? If so can you post it?

Comment: No change done, i just installed a new theme ("Bridge" : https://themeforest.net/item/bridge-creative-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7315054)

Comment: Obviously a problem with the theme. Maybe try changing the home page from whatever it is to a static page, or archive etc and see if the redirect still happens.  That might help you figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a meta tag in your head that is refreshing the page every 0 seconds, back to the same page so it is looping. See here in the console:

[image: meta refresh]

If you cannot think of which part of your code is injecting this refresh, use a text editor to search your files for this string: http-equiv or http-equiv="refresh"
and see if you can find anything relating to this. It could be a plugin that you need to disable or a config file somewhere. But that meta tag is definitely the culprit, nothing on the page is loading past that tag.